# php increment in a loop to achieve results that don't add after 0.9

Tags: php

In a for loop (or any loop) is it possible to increment so that the result is something like:

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
1.10 //Not 2 here, but continue with 1.10, 1.11 etc
1.11
1.12
1.13
```

You get the idea?

I was doing like below, but that adds and turns to 2 after 1.9. Can something like this be achieved without extra code.

```
for ($x=1; $x<=10; $x +=0.1) {

  echo "The number is: $x <br>";

}
```

Comment: This is risky since you can have infinite precision (theoretically). With [PHP floats](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) (64-bit IEEE format) you can have precision up to 14 decimal positions - essentially trillions of iterations. You'll want to limit the precision at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {

  echo "The number is: 1.$i<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<?php
$j=0;$k=1;
for ($x=1; $x<=10;  $x +=0.1) {

  echo "The number is: $k."."$j <br>";
$j++;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 1.1
>   1.2
>   1.3
>   1.4
>   1.5
>   1.6
>   1.7
>   1.8
>   1.9
>   1.10 
>   1.11
>   1.12
>   1.13 ........... upto 1.90

Comment: consider `for ( $x=1, $j=0, $k=1; $x<=10; $x +=0.1, $j++ )`